# Difficulty in loading multiple images in a list view served by multiple xml files

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a html application for Android and I am trying to load images in a list view. Data specific to list items is being served by multiple xml files. I am using ajax to load xml files and populate the list items. Problem I am facing here is that there are 164 list items. Hence, 164 images and 10 xml files to load. my loader function exhausts after two iterations. It does read the xml files but it's unable to dynamically create list items and populate them with images after two iterations. I believe it's due to stack limitations. I can't think of alternate solution. If somebody could suggest an alternate solution that will be highly appreciated. Below is my loader function. It's a recursive function:

```
function loadChannels() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: curURL,
            dataType: "xml",
            error: function(){ console.log('Error Loading Channel XML'); },
            success: function(nXml) {
                var noOfItems = parseInt($($(nXml).find('total_items')[0]).text(), 10);
                var startIdx = parseInt($($(nXml).find('item_startidx')[0]).text(), 10);

                var allItems = $(nXml).find('item');


                $(allItems).each(function() {
                    var obj = $("<li><span id='cont-thumb'></span><span id='cont-name'></span></li>");
                    $("#content-scroller ul").append($(obj));

                    var imgURL = $($(this).find('item_image')[0]).text();
                    var contThumb = $(obj).children()[0];
                    $(contThumb).css("background-image", 'url('+imgURL+')');
                    var name = $($(this).find('name')[0]).text();
                    var contName = $(obj).children()[1];
                    $(contName).text(name).css('text-align', 'center');
                    var url = $($(this).find('link')[0]).text();
                    $(obj).data('item_link', url);
                    $(obj).bind('click', onJPContSelected);                
                });

                if(startIdx+allItems.length < noOfItems){

                    var newIdx = new Number(startIdx+allItems.length);
                    var tokens = curURL.split("/");
                    tokens[tokens.length-2] = newIdx.toString(10);
                    curURL = "http:/";
                    for(var i=2; i<tokens.length; i++)
                        curURL = curURL + "/" + tokens[i];

                    loadChannels();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have even tried to control this behavior using timers but to no avail. It only loads 20 images out of 164. I seriously don't understand what's happening. Any quick help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the recursion with an outer loop - something like that:

```
function loadChannels(){
    var stopFlag = false;
    // request the pages one after another till done
    while(!stopFlag) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: curURL,
            dataType: "xml",
            error: function(){ 
                console.log('Error Loading Channel XML'); 
                errorFlaf = true;
            },
            success: function(nXml) {
                var noOfItems = parseInt($($(nXml).find('total_items')[0]).text(), 10);
                var startIdx = parseInt($($(nXml).find('item_startidx')[0]).text(), 10);
                var allItems = $(nXml).find('item');
                $(allItems).each(function() {
                    var obj = $("<li><span id='cont-thumb'></span><span id='cont-name'></span></li>");
                    $("#content-scroller ul").append($(obj));

                    var imgURL = $($(this).find('item_image')[0]).text();
                    var contThumb = $(obj).children()[0];
                    $(contThumb).css("background-image", 'url('+imgURL+')');
                    var name = $($(this).find('name')[0]).text();
                    var contName = $(obj).children()[1];
                    $(contName).text(name).css('text-align', 'center');
                    var url = $($(this).find('link')[0]).text();
                    $(obj).data('item_link', url);
                    $(obj).bind('click', onJPContSelected);                
                });

                if(startIdx+allItems.length < noOfItems){

                    var newIdx = new Number(startIdx+allItems.length);
                    var tokens = curURL.split("/");
                    tokens[tokens.length-2] = newIdx.toString(10);
                    curURL = "http:/";
                    for(var i=2; i<tokens.length; i++)
                        curURL = curURL + "/" + tokens[i];

                    // lets disable the recursion
                    // loadChannels();
                }
                else {
                    stopFlag = true;
                }
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Yuvi, thanks for your quick response. Adding outer loop causes the loop to run infinite times because AJAX call is asynchronous. I tried to control recursion using timers but that didn't work either. I think it has something to do with heap as I am getting following console message:                                                          dalvikvm-heap(19807): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.130MB for 3850256-byte allocation

Comment: It seems like this problem is specific to HoneyComb. Ice Cream Sandwich and GingerBread render HTML contents correctly.

Comment: Btw: ajax can be set to no async - that what i meant with pages one after another

Comment: Thanks Yuvi for your kind help. As I mentioned this problem is specific to HoneyComb. I am loading web contents in a web view and that's where Android HoneyComb is causing problem.